# How to tell if flex-item is being wrapped

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to apply different styles if a `flex-item` is being wrapped. I can't find any `css` or `js` indicator that a `flex-item` is being wrapped.

The browser has to know that the item is being wrapped...

Where can I bubble that up to effect the styles being applied?

I need to have a "spacer" margin when wrapped, but the margin should be removed when the flex item is not wrapped.

[image: Margin must be applied when wrapped]

[image: Margin should be reduced when not being wrapped]

Comment: There is no "indicator", you'll need media query or script that runs on the resize event

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet as well, so we have with what to work

Comment: Consider the same left margin for all items (or right padding on the container). This takes that issue off the table. Then use absolute positioning to place the brackets where they belong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution that seems best to me, is to add an attributed "wrapped" to each flex child once they are wrapped, and remove it when they are not wrapped. This can be done by comparing the width of the flex-container to the sum of the widths of the flex-children (and the gaps between them, if they exist). I'll post a code snippet once I finish writing it.

There ought to be an attribute added to wrapped flex items by the browser.